Issues when revolving an object around 2 axis(C#)
I have some C# code here, which rotates the camera around the player
The BasePosition is the camera's position used for calculation and the CoreCamera is the camera, The Anchor is the anchor
CoreCamera.Position.X = (float)(Math.Cos(Theta) * (BasePosition.X - Anchor.X) - Math.Sin(Theta) * (BasePosition.Z - Anchor.Z) + Anchor.X);
CoreCamera.Position.Z = (float)(Math.Sin(Theta) * (BasePosition.X - Anchor.X) + Math.Cos(Theta) * (BasePosition.Z - Anchor.Z) + Anchor.Z);
        
CoreCamera.Position.Z = (float)(Math.Cos(Phi) * (BasePosition.Z - Anchor.Z) - Math.Sin(Phi) * (BasePosition.Y - Anchor.Y) + Anchor.Z);
CoreCamera.Position.Y = (float)(Math.Sin(Phi) * (BasePosition.Z - Anchor.Z) + Math.Cos(Phi) * (BasePosition.Y - Anchor.Y) + Anchor.Y);

The rotations work independently, so the maths isn't the problem, mainly, it's when I do both the x and y revolutions
It seems to just do the last rotation I specified, instead of both, and my main goal is to revolve the camera along both axis
How would I achieve this?
I have tried looking for a solution, but they are using code that makes use of rotation matrices, which I'm not using. I would rather fix this code than write entirely new code

I'm not sure if understand the problem correctly, but at first glance it's strange that CoreCamera.Position.Z is set twice. The first value will be overwritten by the second one.

"The BasePosition is the anchor" then what is Anchor?

The Anchor is actually the anchor, sorry, Base Position is the camera's position, just stored in a different variable

When I add both the results, I end up with this weird zoom effect

It is not clear what you mean with "2 axis". A rotation is always around a single axis. Do you mean you want to rotate around an axis not aligned to the X/Y/Z cardinal directions? Or that you want to change the axis with time? Regardless I would highly recommend using a library that provide matrices and quaternions for handling rotations. These tend to be much easier to reason about and to visualize.  like System.Numerics.Matrix4x4.

I mean that I want to rotate the camera along both axis at once, without weird results

That's a plain programming issue.
Mind where the values come from. Both your rotations use BasePosition.
The second one should use CoreCamera.Position.
And you really should learn to enjoy matrices. They make this stuff so much easier to express. You'd have one function that builds you a matrix to rotate around whatever axis by whatever angle. Then you'd matrix-multiply the transforms.

I have tried that, but now the weird zooming rotation is on the Y rotation opposed to the x rotation now. The x rotation also only goes up to 180 degrees and then just flips

Im only rotating on 2 axis, and I don't think gimbal lock can occur on 2 axis, so I would rather use Euler rotation

[mre] please. and/or show us, with pictures, the "weird zooming". your equations might be wrong. or what you consider "weird zooming" is actually correct. who can know?

this is the part of the code causing the problem, and this is the entirety of the math, I cant really minimize it  video with your suggestion , video without your suggestion

[mre] isn't just minimal, but also reproducible. we need to see what else is going on. how the stuff is drawn. how the camera is positioned. etc.

and there are likely more typos in your original code, considering the coordinates (X,Y,Z) that you involve in each rotation. just make a function to abstract over these expressions. this is really not a question that's useful to this site ([help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]). you ought to seek a forum that is specifically for programming beginners, i.e. where people can go to be taught and have their code debugged.
